# Error when installing log.io using npm

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

I am trying to install log.io following the instruction from https://github.com/NarrativeScience/Log.io. It suggests using npm install command.

```
npm install -g log.io
```

The error I am getting is like below. And I tried on both Mac OS and Ubuntu, both no luck. Can anyone help me?

```
> contextify@0.1.13 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/log.io/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssstyle
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssstyle
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 1. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:431:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/log.io/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.25
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chown '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/log.io/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/README.md'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the problems.

### Ubuntu

On Ubuntu 14.04, the default repository of `apt-get` for node is not nodejs itself, but `ax25-node`. This will generate a default command `node` in `/usr/sbin/` and does nothing if you call `node` (which is called by npm during the installation). I removed this package and created a symlink between node and nodejs, finally solved the problem.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove node
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
sudo npm install -g log.io
```

### Mac OS

The error log is quite different from what I got from Ubuntu. After some googling about node-gyp installation failure, I found [this issue](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/489), which led me to install the Xcode dev tools. Not sure why this happens but it seems there are some conflicts between homebrew and Xcode. Anyway, it finally works :-)

Comment: Ubuntu will create the link for you:

```sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-legacy```

You will still want to update your `npm` version, though -- see <https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#updating-node-on-linux>

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a race condition in an older version of `npm`.  There have been a lot of improvements to npm -- especially around conflicts and race conditions during install -- since 1.4. Can you try updating your npm installation?

To update npm on Windows, follow the instructions here: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

If you still see the problem after updating `npm`, could you please upload your npm-debug.log as a  gist http://gist.github.com? If possible, run npm with at least one `-d` flag to increase the logging level.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this. I found the problems. It's not actually an version of npm but a problem for node on Ubuntu. And Xcode issue on Mac.

Answer (score -1):

i create this install package...

http://tinyurl.com/kfnfng6

1 - download it

2 - untar it (tar -xvf install_log.io.tar)

3 - cd install_log.io

4 - sh install.sh

5 - enjoy!

This form is simple and quiet.. i hope help other users...  What i do? simple.. download packages and dependencies , and put all in one package and create a script...

;)